# Thunderbird: How can I modify the server name in the Saved Passwords list

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I need to edit one of the mail server names.

I corrected the mail server name in [email account] > Server Settings > Server Name.

However, when I look at the server name in "Saved Passwords"

Thunderbird > Preferences > Security > Passwords > Saved Passwords

The server name is incorrect.

For the Saved Passwords list, right clicking on an account gives the opportunity to edit Username or Password, but not the server name.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if the server name displayed there is cosmetic and simply hasn't been updated (while the proper value is being used in the Server Settings) or if it is actually used elsewhere. However, if nothing else, it should be possible to delete the saved password. The next time thunderbird needs the password (you can restart thunderbird to immediately trigger a check of mail accounts and thus a need for the password), you should get a prompt to add the password again. In theory, the server name should be updated upon doing this.